# How to 'bind' Text property of a label in markup

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically I would like to find a way to ddo something like:

```
<asp:Label ID="lID" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtId" Text="<%# MyProperty %>"></asp:Label>
```

I know I could set it from code behind (writing lId.Text = MyProperty), but I'd prefer doing it in the markup and I just can't seem to find the solution.
(MyProperty is a string property)
cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Code expressions are an option as well. These can be used inside of quotes in ASP tags, unlike standard <%= %> tags.

The general syntax is:

```
<%$ resources: ResourceKey %>
```

There is a built-in expression for appSettings:

```
<%$ appSettings: AppSettingsKey %>
```

More info on this here: http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx

Comment: I do not think this is an answer for the question since the question specifically asks for the value of a property to be displayed in a label. I do not see how this method provides a way to achieve that.

Comment: using the CodeExpressionBuilder, I could easily display the value of the property on the label. Just check out that blog post, it's quite useful.

Answer (score 11):

You can do

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# MyProperty %>' />
```

And then a Page.DataBind() in the codebehind.

Comment: You left out the % on the left... should be:

    `Text='<%# MyProperty %>'`

Regardless, thanks. You have the only answer which is 99% correct. :)

Also worth noting, you can do this:

    `Text='<%# myClass.MyProperty %>'`

Answer (score 4):

Leave the markup as is and make a call to Page.DataBind(); in your code behind.

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:Label id="lID" runat="server"><%= MyProperty %></asp:Label>
```

since asp.net tags do not allow <% %> constructs, you cannot use Text="<%= MyProperty %>".

Comment: Thanks, I've gone with this solution, but even calling the Page.DataBind() works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Call lID.Databind() from code-behind

Answer (score 0):

```
<div> <%=MyProperty"%></div>
```

Comment: Label control even does not render div tag. May be it would make sense if you suggested <span> but even that would not have the same effect since you avoid all properties of a Label and disallowing the opportunity to use themes.

Comment: yeah, there's no need for a div in my case as I'm using the AssociatedControlId property of the control, to create a label for a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

When you use <%# MyProperty %> declaration you need to databind it, but when using <%= MyProperty %> you don't (which is similar to just writing Response.Write(MyProperty).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblCurrentTime" runat="server">
    Last update: <%=DateTime.Now.ToString()%>
</asp:Label>
```