# ASP.NET 4.0 Server Tags

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

We are migrating ASP.NET project from version 2.0 to 4.0

In previous version i had a specified below line of code:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkContentFilter" 
       Text="<%# SearchResultDictionary.ContentFilter %>" 
       OnCheckedChanged="chkFilterCheckbox_ValueChanged" AutoPostBack="True"
       EnableViewState="True" ></asp:CheckBox>
```

The problem is that in ASP.NET 4.0 `<%# %>` server tag doesn't maps data to control.

Of course there is a workaround to set control Text in code-behind. But i'm interesting is there a way to bind text on aspx layout?

Comment: What you have there seems fine can you tell us what error you are getting ?
And maybe a bit more about "SearchResultDictionary.ContentFilter"

Comment: Check here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558954/asp-net-inline-expression-issue

Comment: I'm not getting any error. Just empty text inside Text field. What i need is to set this text, note that control is not in data-binding control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must call `DataBind()` on the container or control itself for `<%# %>` to be evaluated:

[Data-Binding Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx)

**Markup:**

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkContentFilter" 
       Text='<%# SearchResultDictionary.ContentFilter %>' 
       OnCheckedChanged="chkFilterCheckbox_ValueChanged" AutoPostBack="True"
       EnableViewState="True" ></asp:CheckBox>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
chkContentFilter.DataBind();
```