# Error in binding SqlDataSource data to GridView

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, sqldatasource

I am getting this error:

> Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be
>   used in the context of a databound control.

I am trying to bind `SqlDataSource`'s results to a `GridView`.

This is the code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="grid_getbranch" Height="111px" Width="91px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="branch" SortExpression="branch">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("branch") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("branch") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="grid_getbranch" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:svpolyConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT branch.branch, course.name FROM branch INNER JOIN course ON branch.c_id = course.id WHERE (branch.c_id = @c_id)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList2" Name="c_id" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: sure there isn't any other relevant markup that could be the source of the issue?

Comment: The message is clear, the source of error is not from the markup you're showing, find the stated methods out of the control or in your serverside code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing your SelectCommand query to:

```
SELECT branch.branch AS branch, course.name AS name FROM branch INNER JOIN course ON branch.c_id = course.id WHERE (branch.c_id = @c_id)
```

I'm not sure it's causing your error, but it's the first thing I would try.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Binding to the Label field.

Also refer to this question [How to 'bind' Text property of a label in markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73484/how-to-bind-text-property-of-a-label-in-markup)

Comment: Or use Eval instead of Bind on the Label?

Comment: You cannot bind a text control, you can only bind a **data** field. Here `Bind("name")` *<name** must be data from DB not a textbox or label.