# Bind label to DataSource.TotalRowCount

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, webforms, databinder

I have a custom DataSourceControl class that I'm using somewhat like a view model. I'm coming from WPF databinding land and I would like to be able to bind the text of a label to the TotalRowCount using a databinding expression. I can update the label from the code-behind, but that's not very MVVM. This sample generates a label with blank text:

```
<cc:EquipmentDataSource ID="edsEquipment" runat="server"></cc:EquipmentDataSource>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("edsEquipment.TotalRowCount") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Am I misunderstanding something about how the databinding works? I was getting the same empty string when I used an `ObjectDataSource` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73484/how-to-bind-text-property-of-a-label-in-markup), it would appear two things need to change:

1. You don't need the Eval, the value of the Text attribute can be the property name on your data object.
2. You need to call [Page.DataBind()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.databind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in your code behind.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. Removing the Eval gave me syntax highlighting that showed me TotalRowCount isn't a property of the data source like I thought. It looks like it's a member of the selecting event and I'll have to update a property when that's called.

Answer (score 0):

you must call Page.Databind() in Page_Load Method